# Как ставить Awake'и в очередь

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть несколько скриптов, в одном выполняется в Awake парсинг xml, и значения заносятся в Dictionary, а в других выполняется получение значения из этого Dictionary тоже в Awake, и как сделать чтобы один Awake ждал другой Awake пока то загрузит Xml, и после этого только тогда получить значение из Awake?

Comment: А нафига делать первый скрипт `MonoBehaviour`? Если его задача загрузить и хранить?

Comment: @Yaroslav, xml хранится в сериализуемой переменной типа string (что-бы можно было в инспекторе вставить xml), а Dictionary в который будет распарсен это xml, естественно объявлен как статическое поле .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Unity  можно настроить порядок выполнения скриптов:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html

Так как Awake - выполняется в одном потоке, то один будет ждать другой. При этом приложение зависнет, пока не считает все данные.

Лучше это делать в другом потоке или Coroutines.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/Coroutines.html

И связать свои скрипты колбеками, через события, например.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/

Когда один скрипт закончит чтение, то оповестит другой об этом.

Comment: То есть я могу сделать проверку был ли загружен xml и не выставлять очередь? Я думал, что методы Awake или Start  илиUpdate и.т.д. выполняются асинхронно, А что поток зависнет это хорошо потому что мне нужно загружать файлы локализации

Comment: Да! Последняя ссылка. Если так сделаешь,то когда первый считает Xml, то он вызовет функцию в другом и тот может там обрабатывать результат.